# user of my wifi for texting when visiting my home

Tags: user-tracking

I'm investigating a break and enter at my home. My suspect is someone I considered a friend.

I think he orchestrated a set up with an accomplice. I would like to know if I can get a record of who he contacted using my WiFi router and I can how do I go about doing it?

Comment: Sounds like you should call the police and let them know everything you can about the break-in.

Comment: Some routers have a log feature that can display DHCP leases and MAC addresses that connected to the network, so you could look at them for evidence that someone connected to your network. However, given the omnipresence of encryption in most social networks and messaging apps, you wouldn't be able to get any info such as the context of the messages even if your router was configured to capture all traffic, though most consumer routers don't have such features to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't setup your router to log all communication metadata you will not be able to find out what communications have been transacted using your wifi. The maximum of information you will be able to gather from a home router is a list of the MAC addresses that where connected to your wifi and even that depends on your router.

Comment: Police were contacted however there's that propable cause to ask a judge for a warrent, and all I have is circumstancial evidence  being not a solid reason for a search warrant. So he will be off the hook from the law. Thank you for your responces to my question